Save SQLite Database to Phone Internal Storage
I am trying to save a SQLite Database in phone internal storage same way WhatsApp does it in Android device by creating folder and saving Database there.
How can this be achieved in Codename One App?

Make sure the database is closed and not active. Use getDatabasePath to get the file URL to the location of the database.
You can then copy the content of that file to any place you desire.

I have edited the question. How can Codename One App create a directory/folder in phone internal storage and save files like SQLite database created by the app?

I don't see the change. If you want to copy a file to the phone storage you can use FileSystemStorage to place the file in an arbitrary location but obviously there are limitations imposed by each OS on the writable/readable locations within the filesystem.

Please share an example that uses FileSystemStorage to place a file in an arbitrary location or phone internal storage

In these discussions I didn't find any solution that solves this problem

How can I download files from app storage home/.cn1 or home/.cn1/database to phone's internal storage directory like Downloads? I was checking Util class but seems it downloads from a http url only

The download directory is problematic and platform specific. You need to use an API like share which takes a directory from your home folder and moves it to a different application. Mobile OSs try to isolate applications from one another you can't just write to any directory.

Actually I had tried to use share API.
String databasePath = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("TestDB.db");
String mimeType = "application/vnd.sqlite3";
Display.getInstance().share(databasePath, null, mimeType);
I also tried mimeType  application/x-sqlite3
But instead of sharing DB file, it shares a text like /data/user/0/com.quick.prev/databases/TestDB.db

Which mimeType should I use to be able to share TestDB.db file above?

Use a mime type your application can intercept. You can invent a new one as explained here.

This makes the app to be a share target app like WhatsApp, Emails apps. It adds the app to the OS share dialog. But my aim is different since I just need to be able to share a file. Note I can successfully share other files like pdf, txt using their respective mimetypes.

Then the mime type depends on the target. Other types work great because there are apps to intercept them on the other side.

Since SQLite database can be saved different with file extensions, when sharing the DB, I saved the file to share as TestDB.txt, then used mime type plain/text. Share was successful. Then in the device that received the file, I selected TestDB.txt using FileCooser and successfully saved it in database path as TestDB.db as discussed here

However this workaround creates this situation.

That's unrelated. That encryption is for the Storage API only. Not for FileSystemStorage and it doesn't impact that.

Turns out that after the database file is encrypted using FilesCipher class in this answer, it can NOW be shared as TestDB.db with mimeTypes like application/vnd.sqlite3 and  */*. Therefore no more need to share it as TestDB.txt
